# How to improve the performance searching for directories meeting certain conditions among a huge number of files/dirs?

Tags: python, performance, search

I'm mostly done with the functionality part of a python program I'm writing and now I have to take care of the performance site. The part I first want to optimize is the searching process for directories meeting certain criteria.

In detail:
I'm searching in a certain directory and all subdirectories for folders that contain specific subfolders, because when they do, they are most certainly the folders I'm looking for.

For example, a folder containing the subfolders "wp-content", "wp-admin" and "wp-includes" is most certainly the WordPress installation folder. The chance this is not the case is pretty slim, so I can live with that.

Now the thing is that (in this case) the WordPress installation folder can be anywhere, the only thing I know for sure is that it is somewhere in the html/ directory.

Of course the html/ directory can contain hundreds of thousands of files and subdirectories. If this is the case, this part of my program quickly becomes its bottleneck, so I need to make sure to search in the most efficient way.

What I've originally been doing:

1) Recursively search all directories and subdirectories

2) Configure the maximum search depth

3) Use `os.path.isdir(...)` to check whether (in this case) "wp-content" etc. exist in the current folder.

So the only limitation here is the search depth. I've also thought about:

- Excluding directories form search with more than XXX files in them

  - Problem: Counting the files using `len(os.listdir())` may still slow the program down
- Getting the entire folder tree structure in one go before searching

  - I'm not really sure this is faster
- Excluding directories with certain names that belong most likely to unrelated applications

But first I want to know if there's something on the Python side I can do to improve the performance of my search. It's easy to increase the performance when file reading is involved, but in this case I'm not really reading anything, just checking if directories with a certain path exist. I'm not sure how efficient Python's `os.path.isdir(path)` works. So... are there better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `os.walk` option? it does the recursion and directory tree walking for you...

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: Didn't know about os.walk, will take a closer look at it! Thanks!

Comment: Sadly os.walk does not increase the performance. Creating the entire directory tree costs more time even than going through it step-by-step and stopping when a result was found.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of regex with `os.walk` like below code snippet.
This will find all files starting with two digits and ending in gif, you can add the files into a global list, if you wish:

```
import re
import os
r = re.compile(r'\d{2}.+gif$')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/vinko'):
  l = [os.path.join(root,x) for x in files if r.match(x)]
  if l: print l #Or append to a global list, whatever
```

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll try this and see how much of a difference it makes!

Comment: Sadly os.walk does not increase the performance. Creating the entire directory tree costs more time even than going through it step-by-step and stopping when a result was found (so that further subfolders don't have to be searched any more).